# How to fix "Service [XXX]: SSL server needs a certificate" on an Stunnel server?

Tags: ssl, server, certificate, stunnel

I had an Stunnel server configuration that was working fine last week. It seems that after a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` that is not the case anymore.

Version:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/stunnel
?????????? 1 root root 8 Xxx XX  2016 /usr/bin/stunnel -> stunnel4
$ stunnel -version
stunnel 5.30 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
Compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
Running  with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
Update OpenSSL shared libraries or rebuild stunnel
```

And this is my server `stunnel.conf`

```
verify = 2
debug = 7
output = stunnel.log
options = NO_SSLv3

[XXX]
client = no
verify = 0
accept = 9888
connect = localhost:9879
key = path/to/file.key
CAfile = path/to/ca.pem
```

---

What was working before, now gives to following error:

```
$ sudo stunnel stunnel.conf
[ ] Initializing service [XXX]
[!] Service [XXX]: SSL server needs a certificate
```

---

Why do I need a certificate now? Isn't this a server? I already provided a private key and CA certificate and thought that was enough.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think an Stunnel server doesn't need the clients' certs on the configuration in order to start a session to listen on.

Whatever the issue is. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by changing `CAfile` to `cert`:

```
[XXX]
...
cert = path/to/ca.pem
```